# Intention of tumbleweed badge

Tags: discussion, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I see that in SO, we have the tumbleweed badge.
What exactly is the reason for the introduction of such a badge.
I mean, is it like intended to show that a question is too bad that no one wants to pay attention to it or is it like, unfortunately, somehow, less people viewed the post?

Will a question with such a badge, in turn, draw more attention to it, that way helping people to view the question more and provide an answer?

Comment: 'Sympathy', I reckon. Much like 'Tenacious' and 'Unsung Hero'.

Comment: @Chris, "Unsung hero" is likely not due to Sympathy. More of "encouraging".

Comment: it's an awful badge that makes me feel like the site is laughing at my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question was pretty well answered on Meta Stack Exchange in [What is the purpose of the tumbleweed badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge)

The simplest description comes from [Thomas Owens's accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1579/182513):

> I see it more as a consolation prize. No one looked at your question or answered it, so here's something to hold you over until you get an answer.

But my favorite description actually comes from [the comments under that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge#comment2471_1579):

> `Tumbleweed badge = "Here, have a cookie."` =) –  gnostradamus Jul 1 '09 at 19:14

So to answer your last question, no the badge itself won't draw attention to the post any more than it would have without the badge.  It is one of the very few badges that really aren't based on some sort of reward, encouragement, or education.

Comment: It has occurred that I was looking at the [recent badges list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges#h-recent-badges) and clicked on a _tumbleweed_ badge, so I wouldn't say that  that it would draw the same attention as no badge at all.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what exactly - if any - the *"intention"* is but it can't denote bad questions because bad questions attract negative votes.  To my mind it's just a classification highlighting a ***niche*** area - which might in-turn, be interesting.