# Introducing the Banana Split Badge (formerly Profundity Badge, Controversy Badge originally Banana Split)

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Looking at the following question

[C# is irritating? English too? NO!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256753/c-is-irritating-english-too-no)

I noticed the votes had a breakdown of +33/-33 at one point!
How cool is that?
I think there should be a badge for that!

Let's say when there are + and - above 25 on one question, REWARD a Banana Split Badge!

pro·fun·di·ty (to paraphrase google)
prəˈfəndətē/Submit
noun
deep insight; great depth of knowledge or thought.

great depth or intensity of a state, quality, or emotion.

**a statement or idea that shows great knowledge or insight**.

That's no tumbleweed.

Comment: Maybe i'll get that badge right now!

Comment: What sort of beneficial behavior is reinforced by such a badge?

Comment: The questioner exibits a strong controversial point

Comment: And how is that beneficial?  Controversy for the sake of controversy?

Comment: How about: asking searching questions that expose issues that the community doesn't (edit: yet) have a clear answer for?

Comment: @DNA *[shrug]* Feel free to upvote the proposal, if you agree with it.

Comment: I'd need another 5 people to vote too so OP can have his Banana Split

Comment: I got a BANANA SPLIT! (well not quite...25 is the target)

Comment: @iCodez you're right!

Comment: Related: ["Badge idea: Controversial Badge"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111805/badge-idea-controversial-badge)

Comment: 25 as a magic number would apply much more so here than on SO.  MOST comments on SO dont get nearly that much attention or upvotes.

Comment: If you really want to find out which posts are like this, you can use [my SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185393/find-most-disputed-posts). Just set the min and max values. You can also change it to work on any site in the network.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What sort of beneficial behavior is reinforced by "tumbleweed?"

Comment: @emodendroket: Every rule has an exception.  Including this one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please take a second look

Comment: @DNA , please take a look at the change

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think a badge for editing a question and having the voting turn around on it might be beneficial.

Answer (score 13):

Badges are not designed to be "fun".

Every single one has a defined purpose<sup>1</sup> (although some might be less obvious than others), but in general badges do one of 3 things (and some do more than one):

- Teach users about features of the site
- Encourage positive behavior
- Reward positive contributions to the site.

I fail to see how a badge that is based on nothing more than posting a question that is controversial fits into any of the 3 categories.

<sup>1 - Tumbleweed may be the lone exception since it is more of a reward for posting a question that no one was interested in reading, but that is probably the only exception that I can think of.</sup>

Comment: Tumbleweed maybe counts as a 'consolation prize' badge (as Dukeling notes in [the other current answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256794/237838)); there's only one sort of positive I can think of with it: It presumes the question was not closed or down voted, and not even any, "What have you tried?" or "RTFM" comments.

Comment: @AndrewBarber true... I said "reward", but I could have said [consolation prize or "here, have a cookie"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255770/intention-of-tumbleweed-badge/255773#255773), but regardless of the term, it is still more of an exception to the normal 3 rules.

Comment: Definitely an exception; I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. :)

Answer (score 4):

Note - we don't currently have any badges for getting downvoted (except maybe "Peer Pressure", but that's for **deleting** a downvoted post - the positive part being that you deleted your bad post, not that you posted it in the first place, and "Tumbleweed" is sort of along these lines - but one might see that as more of a consolation prize, and having old questions no-one sees [apparently isn't a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254402/is-closing-old-questions-a-gigantic-waste-of-time-and-effort)).

The general assumption (well, **my** general assumption) is that there's something wrong with anything that gets downvoted (at least in the eyes of the downvoter).

So, with this badge, we'd actively encourage users to do something wrong (but do their best to balance it out with good things to obviously get the amount of required upvotes as well).

Wouldn't it be better if they were to just focus on the good things and try to eliminate the bad?

So no, not a good idea.

---

If you're just talking about Meta, that might be a slightly different story, but we still don't want people to post ideas they *know* are bad to begin with, which they might do if we have such a badge.

Comment: Argh! I posted my 'Consolation prize' comment to psubsee2003's answer before I read your answer!